# Why aren't custom form error messages being displayed in Django 1.11?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

When I first built my application with Django 1.8, I was able to create custom form error messages like this:

```
# forms.py
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    user_age = forms.IntegerField(
        label = 'Your age',
        error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your age},
        widget  =  forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))


# create_user_profile.html
<form method="post" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="form-group form-errors">
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p class="errornote">
        {% if form.errors.items|length == 1 %}
            Please correct the error below.
        {% else %}
           Please correct the errors below.
        {% endif %}
        </p>
    {% endif %}
</div>

<div class="form-group form-errors">
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <p class="errornote">
            {{ error }}
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_user_age">Your age</label>
    {{ form.user_age.errors }}
    {{ form.user_age }}
</div>
```

If the user didn't fill out their 'user_age' form field, the template page would display an error message at the top of the page and the error message for that form field like this:

```
Please correct the error below.

Your age
Please enter your age
+--------------------+
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

However, I recently upgraded from Django 1.8 to Django 1.11 and I've realized that my custom form error messages are no longer being displayed.  Instead, if the user doesn't enter their age in that form field in Django 1.11, a generic message "bubble" that contains an exclamation point is being displayed instead:

```
Your age
+--------------------+
|                    |
+--------------------+
      ! Please fill out this field
```

This happens in all my desktop browsers, Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Brave, etc.

I don't recall reading about this change in the release notes as I went from Django 1.8 to 1.11 (although it's possible I missed it).  What is happening here?  How do I get Django 1.11 to display my custom form field error messages as it did in Django 1.8.

Comment: These are HTML5 validation messages and have nothing to do with Django. The form isn't even being submitted to the backend.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  Do you know if Django has an "opinion" as to how to handle this HTML5 behavior given that it provides a way to customize form error messages?  Searching "disable HTML5 validation messages" is showing that there are ways to handle this.  Frankly, I think my error messages are more instructive.  Thanks again.

Comment: But this still begs the question, "What's changed in Django?"  When I open my production website that's running Django 1.8 in one browser tab and a test version of the site that's running Django 1.11 in a second browser tab, there is no HTML5 validation in the Django 1.8 tab; I see my custom error message.  I only see this HTML5 validation error message in the Django 1.11 tab.

Comment: Of course you can disable them, but as I say that is an HTML matter not a Django one: put `novalidate` in the html form tag.

Comment: Now that I know what to look for, I think this change occurred in Django 1.10.  In the Miscellaneous section of the 1.10 release notes it says the following, "Required form fields now have the required HTML attribute. Set the
Form.use_required_attribute attribute to False to disable it. You could
also add the novalidate attribute to <form> if you don’t want browser
validation."

Comment: I confirmed this is the problem by adding a 'novalidate' attribute to the form.  Once I did that, my custom error message got displayed.  What's interesting is that from that point on, I could *not* enter invalid data (e.g. 'abc') in that integer age field.  It would only accept numbers (either an integer or real number, reals being a different problem). If you want to write this up as an answer, I'd be happy to give you credit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Roseman pointed out, the behavior I was seeing was caused by HTML5 validation being performed client-side.  No data was even being passed back to the server so that my custom form validation could be triggered.  This new behavior was introduced in Django 1.10.  The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.10/#miscellaneous) states,

> Required form fields now have the required HTML attribute. Set the
>   Form.use_required_attribute attribute to False to disable it. You
>   could also add the novalidate attribute to  if you don’t want
>   browser validation. To disable the required attribute on custom
>   widgets, override the Widget.use_required_attribute() method.

As the docs say, you can override this by adding the 'novalidate' attribute to the HTML form.  However, what I found is that if you let Django add the 'required' attribute to all HTML form tags and then add additional custom form validation, you can add an extra level of safety to your forms.  The required attribute will ensure that the user enters *something* in each required field.  But if what they enter is invalid, your form can provide additional validation which will be displayed in the response.  Of course, you can implement full client-side validation using JavaScript and/or Ajax or use a package like [Django-parsley](https://github.com/agiliq/Django-parsley) to forego server-side validation altogether.  This was an interesting learning experience.